# Нужно написать программу на С, которая выполняет то же самое, что и ls -lr в Линуксе

Tags: linux, c

Я пишу, пишу эту программу уже очень давно, но она все равно не заходит в проверяющую систему(неправильный ответ). Хотя когда проверяю в командной строке, как она работает, вроде бы все правильно выдает. Но, видимо, где-то она работает не совсем корректно. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти проблему. Вожусь с задачей уже очень долгое время, но совершенно не понимаю, где может быть проблемы. Буду искренне благодарна

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int comp (const void *i, const void *j) {
    return strcmp(*(const char**)i, *(const char**)j);
}

void fill(char *array, struct stat fStat){
    if(S_ISDIR(fStat.st_mode))
        array[0] = 'd';
    else if(S_ISBLK(fStat.st_mode))
        array[0] = 'b';
    else if(S_ISLNK(fStat.st_mode))
        array[0] = 'l';
    else if(S_ISCHR(fStat.st_mode))
        array[0] = 'c';
    else if(S_ISFIFO(fStat.st_mode))
        array[0] = 'p';


    if (fStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR)
        array[1] = 'r';
    if (fStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR)
        array[2] = 'w';
    if (fStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR)
        array[3] = 'x';
    if (fStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP)
        array[4] = 'w';
    if (fStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP)
        array[5] = 'r';
    if (fStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP)
        array[6] = 'x';
    if (fStat.st_mode & S_IROTH)
        array[7] = 'r';
    if (fStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH)
        array[8] = 'w';
    if(fStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH)
        array[9] = 'x';
}

void print(struct stat Stat, char *fileName, char* currentDirName){
    struct passwd *p = getpwuid(Stat.st_uid);
    char * userString = malloc(100000000 * sizeof(char));
    int temp1 = -1000;
    if(p == NULL){
        temp1 = Stat.st_uid;
    }
    else{
        strcpy(userString, p->pw_name);
    }
    struct group *g = getgrgid(Stat.st_gid);
    char * groupString = malloc(100000000 * sizeof(char));
    int temp2 = -1000;
    if(g == NULL){
        temp2 = Stat.st_gid;
    }
    else{
        strcpy(groupString, g->gr_name);
    }
    char array[11] = "-----------";
    fill(array, Stat);
    printf("%s %ld ", array, Stat.st_nlink);
    if (temp2 == -1 && temp1 == -1) {
        printf("%s %s ", p->pw_name, g->gr_name);
    }
    else if (temp2 == -1 && temp1 != -1) {
        printf("%d %s ", Stat.st_uid, g->gr_name);
    }
    else if (temp2 != -1 && temp1 == -1) {
        printf("%s %d ", p->pw_name, Stat.st_gid);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d %d ", Stat.st_uid, Stat.st_gid);
    }

    printf("%ld %s", Stat.st_size, fileName);

    if (S_ISLNK(Stat.st_mode)) {
        char* link = malloc(100000000 * sizeof(char));
        if (readlink(currentDirName, link, 99999999) == -1) {
             exit(1);
        } else {
            printf(" -> %s", link);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}

int countF(DIR *dir, char **arrayOfFiles){
    int count = 0;
    struct dirent *d;
    while((d = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        arrayOfFiles[count] = malloc((strlen(d->d_name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(arrayOfFiles[count], d->d_name);
        ++count;
    }
    rewnddir(dir);
    return count;
}
void recursion(char *directoryName){
    DIR* dir = opendir(directoryName);
    if(dir == NULL){
        perror("Error");
        closedir(dir);
        exit(1);
    }
    char **arrayOfFiles = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(char*));

    int countOfFiles = countF(dir, arrayOfFiles);

    char **arrayOfDirectories = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(char*));
    int countOfDirectories = 0;
    printf("%s:\n", directoryName);
    qsort(arrayOfFiles, countOfFiles, sizeof(char*), comp);
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfFiles; i++) {
        char *currentDirName = malloc((1000000) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(currentDirName, directoryName);
        if (currentDirName[strlen(currentDirName) - 1] != '/') {
            strcat(currentDirName, "/");
        }
        strcat(currentDirName, arrayOfFiles[i]);
        if (strcmp(arrayOfFiles[i], ".") != 0 && strcmp(arrayOfFiles[i], "..") != 0) {
            struct stat file;
            if (lstat(currentDirName, &file) != 0) {
                perror("");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (S_ISDIR(file.st_mode)) {
                arrayOfDirectories[countOfDirectories++] = currentDirName;
            }
            print(file, arrayOfFiles[i], currentDirName);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfDirectories; i++) {
        recursion(arrayOfDirectories[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        free(arrayOfFiles[i]);
        free(arrayOfDirectories[i]);
    }
    closedir(dir);

}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct stat f;
    if(lstat(argv[1], &f) != 0){
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(!S_ISDIR(f.st_mode)){
        print(f, argv[1], argv[1]);
    }
    else{
        recursion(argv[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте комментарии к коду, что он выполняет в разных частях, так быстрее помогут вам найти ошибку.

Comment: Ваш код даже не компилируется. Вы хотя бы пробовали его откомпилировать?! Что за функция *rewnddir* ? Где она определена?